# Adjust R axis in plots after plot(...) and lines(...)?

Tags: r, plot

t and tt have common days but valuations are not even close so they do not appear in the same plot. Is there some command to adjust the axis to 0:10 in the beginning or after lines command? Some automatic way of doing it so every point appear?

```
t<-structure(list(as.Date.e1.V1....d..m..Y.. = structure(c(15138,
15139, 15140, 15141, 15142, 15145, 15146, 15147, 15148, 15152,
15152), class = "Date"), e1.V2 = c(2.26, 2.82, 2.89, 2.52,
2.19, 2.02, 2.85, 2.99, 2.21, 2.15, 2.22)), .Names = c("as.Date.e1.V1....d..m..Y..",
"e1.V2"), row.names = 3270:3280, class = "data.frame")

tt<-structure(list(as.Date.e2.V1....d..m..Y.. = structure(c(15135,
15138, 15139, 15140, 15141, 15142, 15145, 15146, 15147, 15148,
15152), class = "Date"), e2.V2 = c(11.29, 11.15, 11.25,
11.4, 11.68, 11.08, 9.9, 9.74, 9.46, 9.45, 9.87
)), .Names = c("as.Date.e2.V1....d..m..Y..", "e2.V2"), row.names = 195:205, class = "data.frame")


plot(t)
# How to adjust here the tt so that t and tt can be seen at the same time?
lines(tt)
```

I am sure about the mistake because plotting works with common valuation points:

```
> plot(data.frame(tt[1], log(tt[2])), type='l')
> points(data.frame(t[1], log(t[2])+1.5))
```

[image]

Now without common y -points, you cannot see them in the same plot. So how to adjust it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Building on Geek on Acid's answer, here's a general formulation that addresses the range problem.

```
plot(t,ylim=range(t[2],tt[2]))
lines(tt)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm if I got your question right, you just need to add `ylim` argument to the `plot`, but that is just trivial mate:

```
plot(t,ylim=c(1,15))
lines(tt)
```

[image]

Comment: ...yes, that is the way to do it initially but is there some way to adjust it after the commands or automatically? Suppose I do not know that it is c(0,15), some flag for automatic adjusting? +1 for pointing out the command. I am looking for some generic solution, perhaps just `c(min(values), max(values))` is the way to go with one vector...but suppose I have many values -vectors -- it becomes messy very soon or?

Comment: Ok, I see now. Well, you could also specify the column by doing `plot(t,ylim=c(0,max(tt[,2])))` but as you pointed out it will require you to check which data set have the highest values, so it's not really as robust as you want it...

Comment: yes that is right. I am also considering more accessible adjusting. Just found quite interesting things, perhaps some hack with `locator`, `identify` or something as convenient -- cannot be sure yet, researching...it is often useful to adjust the plot by mouse, not sure whether possible (...perhaps it is called `zooming` not adjusting, thinking aloud).

Comment: It's really not that hard to find max([a_bunch_of_vectors]), so for the general case I recommend you do that to set up your y-axis limits.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: yes but what about with different sized vectors? I used this `valuations<-merge(b1[2],b2[2], all=T); max(valuations)` but it is extremely slow, better ideas? And now if I have many b1, b2, b3, ... I must use for -loop here? Or perhaps just join the values...there must be some cmd, searching.

Comment: @hhh: I'm not sure why you want to create a dataframe.  `max` accepts multiple arguments, so  `max(b1,b2, 3.14159)` will return the max across pi and all elements of the two vectors.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft:  because I want to keeep things clean! `Valuations<--AllValuesHereHow?`? where `AllValuesHereHow?` is a join of different things.  I solved it this way `maxVal<-max(b1[2],b2[2],...); minVal<-min(b1[2],b2[2],...)`, a bit repetitive still... I would like to call the vals just with `valuations`.

Comment: Use `range` as in `plot(t,ylim=range(t[2],tt[2]))`

Answer (score 1):

A generalization to P Lapointe´s answer

```
plot(t,ylim=range(min(min(t),min(tt)),max(max(tt),max(t))))
lines(tt)
```

just in case the second value of each series are not big/small enough.